# Twitter Bootstrap Modal Not Working in DNN

Tags: .net, twitter-bootstrap, dotnetnuke

I am currently running DNN 6.2 and have developed a skin using the toolkit Twitter Bootstrap. All of the functions work correctly except for the Modals.

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

When implemented, I use a HTML/Pro module and import the code through that. For example, if I create a button that calls the modal, when clicked, the overlay appears, the modal drops in, but the modal is behind the overlay.

I've tried:

- adjusting the z-index's
- placing the modal content outside of my skins container, while keeping the button still in the html/pro module.

I would really like to get this function working correctly, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try adjusting the z-index for .DnnModule that class has a z-index of 900 something and always causes problems. In my skins I always set it at 100

You can see a sample of one of my skin.css files at 
https://multifunction.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#skin.css